# Properties of Matrix Product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am studying for my exam next week and the teacher has posted previous exams online.

I have the following question, given:

$A = \begin{bmatrix}4&-2&2\\2&4&-4\\1&1&0\end{bmatrix}$
$u = \begin{bmatrix}1\\3\\2\end{bmatrix}$

Find $A^5*u$ without any calculations...

HINT: Properties of the Matrix Product

Comment: Diagonalization may be a nice try, at the first glance.

Comment: Well, $u$ is an eigenvector of $A$.  Does that help you?

Comment: No, we have not seen eigenvectors yet!

Comment: Without any calculations?

Comment: Yes... In a previous question we have previously calculated the Rank and determined whether it is inversible with Gauss-Jordan elimination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$A  u = \begin{pmatrix}4 & -2 & 2\\ 2 & 4 & -4\\1 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\3\\2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 6 \\ 4\end{pmatrix} = 2 \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 3 \\ 2\end{pmatrix} = 2 u$$

Then for any $n>0$ 
$$A^n u = A^{n-1} (A u)= 2^n u$$

Comment: Sorry, last question is the propriety of Matrix Product that allowed us to do that Associativity?

Comment: Yes, exactly. (Also commutativity of scalars in $A^{n-1} \lambda u = \lambda A^{n-1} u$).